# Generalized Collatz problem mx+r

Tags: reference-request, collatz-conjecture

I'm looking for scientific papers on $9x+r$ and $11x+r$ problem. I once read a paper in which it was stated that no cycles were found in these sequences and probably all sequences are divergent to infinity.

Can anyone help me find it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the end of *[On the “3x+1” problem](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1978-0480321-3)* by R. E Crandall in 1978. He studies the qx+r problem.

Comment: There are only hypotheses, guesses. But there is a publication in which someone computationally searched for cycles in these functions and stated that they were not found.